# How many linked clones does VMware Workstation Pro 16 support?

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, vmware, clone, event-log

I'm on Windows 10 with VMware Workstation Pro 16.1.0 build-17198959. I've created a Win 10 guest VM and created 3 linked clone from it. The three cloned VM are running in parallel and everything works. Today I need 10 VMs with my work, so I created another 7 linked clone from the exactly same snapshot. And, I place 5 of them on a SAMSUNG 960 PRO m.2 SSD drive, and the other 5 on another SAMSUNG 960 PRO m.2 SSD drive. After that, I started these VMs one by one. When I started the 7th VM, my computer got a blue screen and I have to restart it. Then I tried again, but the OS dead again and I don't know what triggered it. I checked the event viewer and found there are some related entries. But I'm not an expert on it. Could anyone help me to take a look of the events I exported? In the events, the issue started at around 4:31 pm and 4:36 pm. You can get it from https://disk.yandex.com/d/Tz-A1hhRrZIEGQ

Btw, generally, how many link-cloned VM can be running in parallel? I have run 3 without any issues in the past. If I create them as fully cloned VMs, can I run more? My computer is pretty beefy, and I have i9-7940x, 128G Ram and a Titan V video card. How many VMs do you think I can run in parallel (Let's say I give each VM 8G RAM)?

Thanks!

Comment: It may simply be a bug. You should be contacting VMware support.

Comment: @DanielB I've already created a post on VMware forum. I posted here just want to get some feedback from other users.

Comment: There is no specific limit to the number of linked clones you can create and run.   There's nothing really special about linked clones in this regard.  Host resources will limit the number of virtual machines you can have running simultaneously.